# Generate reports in background and by schedule using Spring

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, scheduled-tasks

There are 2 ways user can generate a report.

1. User click a button on the front end and job will run to generate the report.
2. User can schedule the report to generate weekly, monthly, etc.

On scenario 1, I decided to first save the request to a table, say **"REQUEST_TBL"**.  Right after that, I will run `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` which picks up the specific request from "REQUEST_TBL".  There could be a lot of users that can request to generate a report.  But each user is given only up to 30 reports to generate for life (if user wants to generate a new report, he needs to delete any old reports).

On scenario 2, user can schedule a certain report to generate weekly, or monthly.  Then a weekly (or monthly or etc) job will run and generate this report that the user scheduled.

Now, I am not sure on how to implement the report generator job.  Whether I use `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` or not.  Or use the same program to handle user request and user scheduled request for report.

I am planning to let one job to run every minute to read "REQUEST_TBL" and for each record I will run ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.execute().  But if there are 1000 users all the same time they requested report, then how should I implement the creation of thread.  Also for the scheduled job, I am planning to run it endofday only.  The scheduled job will read from the same "REQUEST_TBL" and look for request that is scheduled.  For scenario 1, if I want to run a job for every, say, 2 minutes, until what time should I run it?  Cause it may be that at the end of that day, a scheduled report will need to run.  Also, I thought of running a job for every, say 2 minutes, because if the server went down, there's no way to regenerate the report once the server is started.

I would appreciate your suggestion

Comment: Have you looked at Spring Batch? http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/

Answer (score 0):

You are asking many question at once. So few thoughts here:

- definitely don't create thread yoursels. Use rather one of the [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) and limit the number of threads in this way.
- for the rest I'll do it in the most consistent way: every record in `REQUEST_TBL` will also have time when it needs to be generated. So in scenario 1 you will save current time together with the request. With the scenario 2 you'll create a record(s) with timestamp which is week (months) ahead.
- then you can run a job every minute or two to query requests with request time before or equal `now`. And schedule a job to the executor for each returned record.

Comment: sorry, my wordings were wrong.  i edited my question.  what i will do is not create thread but run ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.execute().  I am not sure if running this execute() just after user request is good.  I am also not that good in threading sorry. :(